# Polymorphism on virtual classes with bad_alloc

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, polymorphism, try-catch

I am starting out with c++, out of curiosity I am trying to catch exceptions with polymorphism. I am observing diff behaviours when trying to catch an `std` exception like `bad_alloc` vs my custom exception

In case 1 I am throwing a `bad_alloc` exception which is caught by the catch statement with the argument (`exception e`) the what statement displays the exception to be `bad_alloc()`.

In case 2 I am throwing `MyException` which is derived from exception class this is caught by the catch statement with the argument (`exception e`) the what statement displays the exception to be an `"Unknown exception"` by which I could figure it was calling the `what()` function of the base class exception.

In case 3 I am able to call the `what()` function of child class `MyException` from the catch while using pointers and `"My custom Exception"` is getting printed

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyException : public exception {
public:

    const char* what() const throw() {
        return "My custom Exception";
    }
};
int main() {    

    try {
        bool case1 = false, case2=true, case3=true;
        if (case1) {
            throw bad_alloc(); 
        }
        if (case2) {
            throw MyException();
        }
        if (case3) {
            MyException* o = new MyException();
            throw o;
        }
        
    }   
    catch (exception* e) {
        cout << endl << "catching exception with polymorphism, exception type  is " << e->what();

    }
    catch (exception e) {
        cout << endl << "catching exception with polymorphism  exception type  is " << e.what();

    }

}
```

My doubt is how is the `bad_alloc` exception able to call the `what()` function of itself when there is a rule that Virtual functions(`what()` in this case) should be accessed using a pointer or reference of base class type to achieve run time polymorphism. Here in this scenario, the virtual function is being accessed by the child class object directly in polymorphism.

Comment: Try `catch (exception& e)`.

Comment: You are slicing look here [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: You have object slicing as expected for case 1 and 2.

Comment: Example can be changed to test all cases with loop, for example like [that](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33fb8f248af80a7c).

Comment: @jarod42 with object slicing in case1 and case2 why am I able to call what() method of child in case 1 but in case 2 what() of parent is called. Can somebody explain why is this?

Comment: @molbdnilo by using  reference I might get this working, as in the case of (exception* e) but my question is why bad_alloc exception works even without catch (exception& e) ?

Comment: In provided link, I got `std::exception` for both slicing cases, no `bad_alloc`...

Comment: @jarod42 are you refering to my code? Not sure which link you meant in your comment when you said "provided link"

Comment: in my code you can make case1=true to get bad_alloc from e.what()

Comment: I rewrote your code to show all case in my second comment. and even if I use your code (by changing case1 to true), I got `std::exception` [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c63772b9df7c9560). provide compiler might help to reproduce issue.

Comment: @molbdnilo If you want to be fully correct then use catch(const exception& e) ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 I am using visual studio compiler on windows. Let me try this in g++ and look into exception and get back

Comment: @Jarod42 I am getting expected behaviour with g++, the issue is only with visual studio compiler.

Comment: I am getting  issue is only with visual studio compiler on windows? I didnt know compilers and OS would cause such changes in c++, New learnings.

Comment: The standard doesn't define what `exception::what()` returns. An implementation may choose to make it so an `exception` copy-constructed from `bad_alloc` returns the string `"bad_alloc"` from `what()`; or it may choose not to.